# Looking for a good open source library for cpp sockets usage, including sending large files?

Tags: open-source, library, c++, networking

I am building a client/server app that needs to allow for both basic messaging(Text) and file transfer, possibly including large files over a local network(IP/Port already known of both devices). I also want to be able to encrypt both of these data streams eventually.

I have looked into doing this with sockets, as well as taken a look at some open source apps that perform similar functions (with sockets). It seems there are a lot of things that can go wrong easily, and lots of common implementations. To me this seems like the perfect scenario for an open source library, and yet I can not seem to find one that is well regarded, especially for the file transfer scenario. I am looking for suggestions around that, rather than reinventing that wheel.

Preferably I could simply say on one side

```
HelperFunc::SendFile(fd, path/to/file);

HelperFunc::SetCallbackWhenGettingFile([](string fileNameFromSender{
saveTheFile(pathToSaveTo/fileNameFromSender)})

HelperFunc::SendMessage("Hi");
```

and trust that the file will go where I want it, or that messages will be delivered. When I looked at other projects implementation (embedded with the rest of the app) they would generally have a standardized message that prefaced all others noting the length of the actual message, to help get around some of the issues